# Add Logo image to iphone globally across the Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to show image(Logo) which is below the navigation bar in  all my pages.

i am implementing

```
 @implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)  
 (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
 {  
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"logo.png"];  
     [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width/2, 40, 89, 42)];  
 }
```

in appdelegate
it won't work out .Is this possible to use image  globally or any other better way?

Answer (score 0):

**Add this in AppDelegate.m file**

> -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
>   {
>   navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
>   [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
>   UIImageView *mImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"apple_small_icon"]];
>   [mImage setFrame:CGRectMake(270, 5, 35, 35)];
>   [navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:mImage] ;
>   [mImage release];
>   }

**Add this in AppDelegate.h file**

> UINavigationController *navigationController;

:)